# JavaScript - Uncaught ReferenceError: my function is not defined

Tags: javascript, function, reference

can somebody help why i get this error?

Uncaught ReferenceError: selected_1 is not defined

Uncaught ReferenceError: selected_2 is not defined

Here is my code:

```
<img src="/css/img/firstRoom_selected.png" onclick="selected_1()" id="firstRoom" style="cursor:pointer;">
<img src="/css/img/secondRoom.png" onclick="selected_2()" style=" cursor:pointer;">

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
  function selected_1() {

    if (document.getElementById("firstRoom").src == "/css/img/firstRoom.png") 
    {
        document.getElementById("firstRoom").src = "/css/img/firstRoom_selected.png";
    }
}

  function selected_2() {

    if (document.getElementById("firstRoom").src == "/css/img/firstRoom_selected.png") 
    {
        document.getElementById("firstRoom").src = "/css/img/firstRoom.png";
        document.getElementById("secondRoom").src = "/css/img/secondRoom_selected.png";
    }
}
});
</script>
```

Thanks a lot in advance! :)

Comment: Did you tried writing the image tags after script tags

Comment: you're attaching the event handlers before the dom is ready but defining the functions when the dom is ready

Comment: Scope issue, again...

Answer (score 0):

Your no need to use `$( document ).ready`

```
<img src="/css/img/firstRoom_selected.png" onclick="selected_1()" id="firstRoom" style="cursor:pointer;">
<img src="/css/img/secondRoom.png" onclick="selected_2()" style=" cursor:pointer;">
```

And js:

```
<script>
  function selected_1() {

    if (document.getElementById("firstRoom").src == "/css/img/firstRoom.png") 
    {
        document.getElementById("firstRoom").src = "/css/img/firstRoom_selected.png";
    }
}

  function selected_2() {

    if (document.getElementById("firstRoom").src == "/css/img/firstRoom_selected.png") 
    {
        document.getElementById("firstRoom").src = "/css/img/firstRoom.png";
        document.getElementById("secondRoom").src = "/css/img/secondRoom_selected.png";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: okay, thanks! but now nothing happens when i click on one of the images?

Answer (score 0):

It'd be better to do it like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#firstRoom').click(selected_1)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You've defined your functions inside another anonymous function using `$document.ready`, hence it's not visible to the global scope.

Your images are looking for `selected_1` and `selected_2` in the global scope and hence couldn't find it.

define your function outside `$(document).ready` handler

if you wish to use functions within handler then attach click handlers within ready function. try this script

you should also look into preloading images, that will be another question.

```
<script>
  function selected_1() {
    if (document.getElementById("firstRoom").src == "/css/img/firstRoom.png") {
        var image = new Image()
        image.src = "/css/img/firstRoom_selected.png";
        document.getElementById("firstRoom").src = image.src
    }
}

  function selected_2() {
    if (document.getElementById("firstRoom").src == "/css/img/firstRoom_selected.png") {
        var image = new Image()
        image.src = "/css/img/firstRoom.png";
        document.getElementById("firstRoom").src = image.src

        var image2 = new Image()
        image2.src = "/css/img/secondRoom_selected.png";
        document.getElementById("secondRoom").src = image2.src
    }
}
</script>
```